# How to add a specific meta tag to a PHP page for Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, seo, meta-tags

Can anyone please help me or point me at the right direction?

I'm trying to add a meta tag to a PHP page in a single wordpress page but just wondering if I'm doing it correctly?

```
 <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, XML, XHTML, JavaScript">
```

Where should I put that code into?
Under the get header part?

The other pages on the website somehow already got the meta tag inserted automatically via Yeost SEO plugin, but it's just one page that cannot be added with meta tag via Wordpress panel.

Dev team mentioned that it has to be added manually in the .php page but I'm lost right now on what to do.

Comment: [RTM.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Meta_Tags_in_WordPress)

Comment: This is entirely pointless. Nothing useful cares about meta keywords.